# Since with had been (the past perfect tense)

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

Please check the below sentences and let me know, is this correct or not. As per me **had been** (the past perfect tense) should not be used with **since**.

As per my friend:

I had been writing since childhood.

As per me, it should be:

I have been writing since childhood.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incidentally, in AmE (and as far as I know in BrE), *as per*  is only used in commercial and bureaucratic registers. In ordinary speech and academic writing we say *according to*.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect constructions speak about a state which obtains at Reference Time—the time which your discourse addresses—as a result of some prior event. Present perfect and past perfect address different Reference Times.

Present perfect speaks about a present Reference Time:

> I am about to start my first novel, but I **have been writing** since childhood. ... *This speaks about my present writing experience.*

Past perfect speaks about a past Reference Time:

> In 2003 I started my first novel, but I **had been writing** since childhood. ... *This speaks about my writing experience in 2003.*

You may read more (much more, possibly, than you want) about the meaning and use of perfect constructions [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32).

Answer (score 1):

If you have been taking pen to paper since childhood-- but no longer write (or if your current status as a writer is undetermined) say: "I **had** been writing since childhood." [You did write in the past.]

If you used to do this-- and still do-- say: "I **have** been writing since childhood." [You did write in the past and do so now.]